# Java Complex Numbers, 3 Classes

Tags: java

I'll repeat what I have to do in [java](/questions/tagged/java), in the way I think I need to think in order to complete this mission. (Sorry, I'm new to programming).

First class; define class for complex numbers. I found this fairly easy and my answer is below.

```
public class Complex {
    private double real;
    private double imaginary;

    public Complex()
    {
        this( 0.0, 0.0 );
    }

    public Complex( double r, double i )
    {
        real = r;
        imaginary = i;
    } 
}
```

Second class; add and subtract with public static methods, recalling real and imaginary from first class. This part I found a little bit more challenging as I don't 100% grasp this.

```
Public class ComplexArith
public static ComplexAdd(Complex one, Complex two)
return Complex(one.getReal() + two.getReal(), one.getImaginary() + two.getImaginary());

public static ComplexSub(Complex one, Complex two)
return Complex(one.getReal() - two.getReal(), one.getImaginary - two.getImaginary());
```

The third part is to ask for user input, and add and subtract the set of complex numbers. I'm unfamiliar with this as I've never had to ask for user input in a (0.0,0.0) format.

Any insight on the overall code? Am I even on the right track?

EDIT:

The first class I banged out. Thanks to you guys.

Second class I'm having compiling issues because I'm not fully understanding something.

```
public class ComplexArith{
public static Complex add(Complex one, Complex two)
{
return Complex(one.getReal() + two.getReal(), one.getImaginary() + two.getImaginary());
}
public static Complex sub(Complex one, Complex two)
{
return Complex(one.getReal() - two.getReal(), one.getImaginary - two.getImaginary());
}
}
```

I know that one and two need to be defined, but I'm not understanding how to define them. What would I define them as? I thought it was being called from class Complex from double r, double i.

I also thought `.getImaginary` was being defined as well in the first class. Here is the first class.

```
public class Complex
{
private double real;
private double imaginary;

public Complex()
{
    this( 0.0, 0.0 );
}


public Complex( double r, double i )
{
    real = r;
    imaginary = i;
}

public double getReal() {
  return this.real;
}

public double getImaginary() {
  return this.imaginary;
}
}
```

Comment: Use the keyword new (`return new Complex(...)`) to instantiate an object of type Complex. That's what signals it to call the constructor (`public Complex(double r, double i)`). And `getImaginary()` is the method signature, not `getImaginary` - which refers to a non-existent variable

Answer (score 2):

Well you're on the right track, but you need getters on your `Complex` object.

For example:

```
   public class Complex
{
    private double real;
    private double imaginary;

    public Complex()
    {
        this( 0.0, 0.0 );
    }


    public Complex( double r, double i )
    {
        real = r;
        imaginary = i;
    }

    public double getReal() {
      return this.real;
    }

    public double getImaginary() {
      return this.imaginary;
    }
}
```

You also need return types on your methods:

```
public class ComplexArith
{   
    public static Complex complexAdd(Complex one, Complex two) {
        return Complex(one.getReal() + two.getReal(),
                      one.getImaginary() + two.getImaginary());
    }

    public static Complex complexSub(Complex one, Complex two) {
        return Complex(one.getReal() - two.getReal(),
                       one.getImaginary - two.getImaginary());
    }
}
```

Also, it has nothing to do with the functionality of your program, but it's customary to have your methods use `camelCase`.  So your methods should look like this:

```
public static Complex complexAdd(Complex one, Complex two) {
    return Complex(one.getReal() + two.getReal(), 
                  one.getImaginary() + two.getImaginary());
}
```

Comment: +1 for camelCase mention. I initially read the methods as constructors. I had to blink a few times to follow what was going on.

Comment: Ah thanks so much. I really appreciate the feedback.
I can understand what I need to do (I have a nice little flowchart in my head), it's just Im unfamiliar with the bits of code that I need to accomplish what I need to. I'm going to tinker around with the code for a little bit and I'll post back what I solve.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'd put those arithmetic operations in the Complex class.  Those are truly operations on Complex numbers, so I wouldn't encapsulate them outside the Complex class.

I'd think about making Complex immutable.  It's thread safe that way.

I like the static add, sub, mul, div methods.  Be sure that they return a Complex (they don't now).  Other methods, like cosine, sine, etc. might belong in a Math class in your complex package.  See the java.lang.Math for an example for real numbers.

You need to return "new Complex".  The code you wrote won't compile.

Comment: Agreed, but if the assignment called for the math being done by a second class with static methods, then the OP is stuck with that.

Comment: True enough, just not my preference.  I'd argue against doing it that way, even if the assignment said that it must be done that way.  Better to think about good reasons for it.

Comment: Yeah, I am stuck with those. I would think that doing it all within one class would make life a lot easier for me.

Answer (score 2):

this is my implementation, i do all on one class:

```
package name.puzio.math;

public final class ComplexNumber {
private final double imaginary;
private final double real;

@Override
public final boolean equals(Object object) {
    if (!(object instanceof ComplexNumber))
        return false;
    ComplexNumber a = (ComplexNumber) object;
    return (real == a.real) && (imaginary == a.imaginary);
}

public ComplexNumber(double real, double imaginary) {
    this.imaginary = imaginary;
    this.real = real;
}

public static final ComplexNumber createPolar(double amount, double angel) {
    return new ComplexNumber(amount * Math.cos(angel), amount * Math.sin(angel));
}

public final double getImaginary() {
    return imaginary;
}

public final double getReal() {
    return real;
}

public final double getAmount() {
    return Math.sqrt((real * real) + (imaginary * imaginary));
}

public final double getAngle() {
    return Math.atan2(imaginary, real);
}

public final ComplexNumber add(ComplexNumber b) {
    return add(this, b);
}

public final ComplexNumber sub(ComplexNumber b) {
    return sub(this, b);
}

public final ComplexNumber div(ComplexNumber b) {
    return div(this, b);
}

public final ComplexNumber mul(ComplexNumber b) {
    return mul(this, b);
}

public final ComplexNumber conjugation() {
    return conjugation(this);
}

/**
 * Addition:
 * @param a
 * @param b
 * @return
 */
private final static ComplexNumber add(ComplexNumber a, ComplexNumber b) {
    return new ComplexNumber(a.real + b.real, a.imaginary + b.imaginary);
}

/**
 * Subtraktion:
 * @param a
 * @param b
 * @return
 */
private final static ComplexNumber sub(ComplexNumber a, ComplexNumber b) {
    return new ComplexNumber(a.real - b.real, a.imaginary - b.imaginary);
}

/**
 * Multiplikation:
 * @param a
 * @param b
 * @return
 **/
private final static ComplexNumber mul(ComplexNumber a, ComplexNumber b) {
    return new ComplexNumber((a.real * b.real) - (a.imaginary * b.imaginary), (a.imaginary * b.real) + (a.real * b.imaginary));
}

/**
 * Division:
 * @param a
 * @param b
 * @return
 **/
private final static ComplexNumber div(ComplexNumber a, ComplexNumber b) {
    double d = (b.real * b.real) + (b.imaginary * b.imaginary);
    if (d == 0)
        return new ComplexNumber(Double.NaN, Double.NaN);
    return new ComplexNumber(((a.real * b.real) + (a.imaginary * b.imaginary)) / d, ((a.imaginary * b.real) - (a.real * b.imaginary)) / d);
}

/**
 * Konjugation:
 * @param a
 * @return
 **/

private final static ComplexNumber conjugation(ComplexNumber a) {
    return new ComplexNumber(a.real, -a.imaginary);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're somewhat on the right track given what you state are the assignments.

However, in your second class you are calling `getReal()` and `getImaginary()` methods on `Complex` objects.  But their definitions don't show up anywhere in the `Complex` class definition.

And your methods in `ComplexArith` have no return types.

Those alone will prevent your code from compiling as-is.

Comment: I shortly came to this realization. I added .getImaginary and .getReal to my first class, however I'm still getting a compiling error stated as: cannot find symbol
return Complex(one.getReal() - two.getReal(), one.getImaginary - two.getImaginary());
                                                 ^
  symbol:   variable getImaginary
  location: variable one of type Complex
2 errors

which boggles me even more.

Comment: @user1316703 That is because your `sub` method is missing a paranthesis for the getImaginary method call and thus the compiler is trying to interpret as a variable. `return Complex(one.getReal() - two.getReal(), one.getImaginary - two.getImaginary());` The `one.getImaginary` should be `one.getImaginary()`

Answer (score 0):

Though this already been answered I thought people may benefit by the following class which does a lot of functions related to Complex Numbers.

This has been released under MIT License and the GitHub project is [here](https://github.com/abdulfatir/jcomplexnumber/).

```
/**
 * <code>ComplexNumber</code> is a class which implements complex numbers in Java. 
 * It includes basic operations that can be performed on complex numbers such as,
 * addition, subtraction, multiplication, conjugate, modulus and squaring. 
 * The data type for Complex Numbers.
 * <br /><br />
 * The features of this library include:<br />
 * <ul>
 * <li>Arithmetic Operations (addition, subtraction, multiplication, division)</li>
 * <li>Complex Specific Operations - Conjugate, Inverse, Absolute/Magnitude, Argument/Phase</li>
 * <li>Trigonometric Operations - sin, cos, tan, cot, sec, cosec</li>
 * <li>Mathematical Functions - exp</li>
 * <li>Complex Parsing of type x+yi</li>
 * </ul>
 * 
 * @author      Abdul Fatir
 * @version     1.1
 * 
 */
public class ComplexNumber
{
    /**
    * Used in <code>format(int)</code> to format the complex number as x+yi
    */
    public static final int XY = 0;
    /**
    * Used in <code>format(int)</code> to format the complex number as R.cis(theta), where theta is arg(z)
    */
    public static final int RCIS = 1;
    /**
    * The real, Re(z), part of the <code>ComplexNumber</code>.
    */
    private double real;
    /**
    * The imaginary, Im(z), part of the <code>ComplexNumber</code>.
    */
    private double imaginary;
    /**
    * Constructs a new <code>ComplexNumber</code> object with both real and imaginary parts 0 (z = 0 + 0i).
    */
    public ComplexNumber()
    {
        real = 0.0;
        imaginary = 0.0;
    }

    /**
    * Constructs a new <code>ComplexNumber</code> object.
    * @param real the real part, Re(z), of the complex number
    * @param imaginary the imaginary part, Im(z), of the complex number
    */

    public ComplexNumber(double real, double imaginary)
    {
        this.real = real;
        this.imaginary = imaginary;
    }

    /**
    * Adds another <code>ComplexNumber</code> to the current complex number.
    * @param z the complex number to be added to the current complex number
    */

    public void add(ComplexNumber z)
    {
        set(add(this,z));
    }

    /**
    * Subtracts another <code>ComplexNumber</code> from the current complex number.
    * @param z the complex number to be subtracted from the current complex number
    */

    public void subtract(ComplexNumber z)
    {
        set(subtract(this,z));
    }

    /**
    * Multiplies another <code>ComplexNumber</code> to the current complex number.
    * @param z the complex number to be multiplied to the current complex number
    */

    public void multiply(ComplexNumber z)
    {
        set(multiply(this,z));
    }
    /**
    * Divides the current <code>ComplexNumber</code> by another <code>ComplexNumber</code>.
    * @param z the divisor
    */  
    public void divide(ComplexNumber z)
    {
        set(divide(this,z));
    }
    /**
    * Sets the value of current complex number to the passed complex number.
    * @param z the complex number
    */
    public void set(ComplexNumber z)
    {
        this.real = z.real;
        this.imaginary = z.imaginary;
    }
    /**
    * Adds two <code>ComplexNumber</code>.
    * @param z1 the first <code>ComplexNumber</code>.
    * @param z2 the second <code>ComplexNumber</code>.
    * @return the resultant <code>ComplexNumber</code> (z1 + z2).
    */
    public static ComplexNumber add(ComplexNumber z1, ComplexNumber z2)
    {
        return new ComplexNumber(z1.real + z2.real, z1.imaginary + z2.imaginary);
    }

    /**
    * Subtracts one <code>ComplexNumber</code> from another.
    * @param z1 the first <code>ComplexNumber</code>.
    * @param z2 the second <code>ComplexNumber</code>.
    * @return the resultant <code>ComplexNumber</code> (z1 - z2).
    */  
    public static ComplexNumber subtract(ComplexNumber z1, ComplexNumber z2)
    {
        return new ComplexNumber(z1.real - z2.real, z1.imaginary - z2.imaginary);
    }
    /**
    * Multiplies one <code>ComplexNumber</code> to another.
    * @param z1 the first <code>ComplexNumber</code>.
    * @param z2 the second <code>ComplexNumber</code>.
    * @return the resultant <code>ComplexNumber</code> (z1 * z2).
    */  
    public static ComplexNumber multiply(ComplexNumber z1, ComplexNumber z2)
    {
        double _real = z1.real*z2.real - z1.imaginary*z2.imaginary;
        double _imaginary = z1.real*z2.imaginary + z1.imaginary*z2.real;
        return new ComplexNumber(_real,_imaginary);
    }
    /**
    * Divides one <code>ComplexNumber</code> by another.
    * @param z1 the first <code>ComplexNumber</code>.
    * @param z2 the second <code>ComplexNumber</code>.
    * @return the resultant <code>ComplexNumber</code> (z1 / z2).
    */      
    public static ComplexNumber divide(ComplexNumber z1, ComplexNumber z2)
    {
        ComplexNumber output = multiply(z1,z2.conjugate());
        double div = Math.pow(z2.mod(),2);
        return new ComplexNumber(output.real/div,output.imaginary/div);
    }

    /**
    * The complex conjugate of the current complex number.
    * @return a <code>ComplexNumber</code> object which is the conjugate of the current complex number
    */

    public ComplexNumber conjugate()
    {
        return new ComplexNumber(this.real,-this.imaginary);
    }

    /**
    * The modulus, magnitude or the absolute value of current complex number.
    * @return the magnitude or modulus of current complex number
    */

    public double mod()
    {
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(this.real,2) + Math.pow(this.imaginary,2));
    }

    /**
    * The square of the current complex number.
    * @return a <code>ComplexNumber</code> which is the square of the current complex number.
    */

    public ComplexNumber square()
    {
        double _real = this.real*this.real - this.imaginary*this.imaginary;
        double _imaginary = 2*this.real*this.imaginary;
        return new ComplexNumber(_real,_imaginary);
    }
    /**
    * @return the complex number in x + yi format
    */
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        String re = this.real+"";
        String im = "";
        if(this.imaginary < 0)
            im = this.imaginary+"i";
        else
            im = "+"+this.imaginary+"i";
        return re+im;
    }
    /**
    * Calculates the exponential of the <code>ComplexNumber</code>
    * @param z The input complex number
    * @return a <code>ComplexNumber</code> which is e^(input z)
    */
    public static ComplexNumber exp(ComplexNumber z)
    {
        double a = z.real;
        double b = z.imaginary;
        double r = Math.exp(a);
        a = r*Math.cos(b);
        b = r*Math.sin(b);
        return new ComplexNumber(a,b);
    }
    /**
    * Calculates the <code>ComplexNumber</code> to the passed integer power.
    * @param z The input complex number
    * @param power The power.
    * @return a <code>ComplexNumber</code> which is (z)^power
    */
    public static ComplexNumber pow(ComplexNumber z, int power)
    {
        ComplexNumber output = new ComplexNumber(z.getRe(),z.getIm());
        for(int i = 1; i < power; i++)
        {
            double _real = output.real*z.real - output.imaginary*z.imaginary;
            double _imaginary = output.real*z.imaginary + output.imaginary*z.real;
            output = new ComplexNumber(_real,_imaginary);
        }
        return output;
    }
    /**
    * Calculates the sine of the <code>ComplexNumber</code>
    * @param z the input complex number
    * @return a <code>ComplexNumber</code> which is the sine of z.
    */
    public static ComplexNumber sin(ComplexNumber z)
    {
        double x = Math.exp(z.imaginary);
        double x_inv = 1/x;
        double r = Math.sin(z.real) * (x + x_inv)/2;
        double i = Math.cos(z.real) * (x - x_inv)/2;
        return new ComplexNumber(r,i);
    }
    /**
    * Calculates the cosine of the <code>ComplexNumber</code>
    * @param z the input complex number
    * @return a <code>ComplexNumber</code> which is the cosine of z.
    */
    public static ComplexNumber cos(ComplexNumber z)
    {
        double x = Math.exp(z.imaginary);
        double x_inv = 1/x;
        double r = Math.cos(z.real) * (x + x_inv)/2;
        double i = -Math.sin(z.real) * (x - x_inv)/2;
        return new ComplexNumber(r,i);
    }
    /**
    * Calculates the tangent of the <code>ComplexNumber</code>
    * @param z the input complex number
    * @return a <code>ComplexNumber</code> which is the tangent of z.
    */
    public static ComplexNumber tan(ComplexNumber z)
    {
        return divide(sin(z),cos(z));
    }
    /**
    * Calculates the co-tangent of the <code>ComplexNumber</code>
    * @param z the input complex number
    * @return a <code>ComplexNumber</code> which is the co-tangent of z.
    */
    public static ComplexNumber cot(ComplexNumber z)
    {
        return divide(new ComplexNumber(1,0),tan(z));
    }
    /**
    * Calculates the secant of the <code>ComplexNumber</code>
    * @param z the input complex number
    * @return a <code>ComplexNumber</code> which is the secant of z.
    */
    public static ComplexNumber sec(ComplexNumber z)
    {
        return divide(new ComplexNumber(1,0),cos(z));
    }
    /**
    * Calculates the co-secant of the <code>ComplexNumber</code>
    * @param z the input complex number
    * @return a <code>ComplexNumber</code> which is the co-secant of z.
    */
    public static ComplexNumber cosec(ComplexNumber z)
    {
        return divide(new ComplexNumber(1,0),sin(z));
    }
    /**
    * The real part of <code>ComplexNumber</code>
    * @return the real part of the complex number
    */
    public double getRe()
    {
        return this.real;
    }
    /**
    * The imaginary part of <code>ComplexNumber</code>
    * @return the imaginary part of the complex number
    */
    public double getIm()
    {
        return this.imaginary;
    }
    /**
    * The argument/phase of the current complex number.
    * @return arg(z) - the argument of current complex number
    */
    public double getArg()
    {
        return Math.atan2(imaginary,real);
    }
    /**
    * Parses the <code>String</code> as a <code>ComplexNumber</code> of type x+yi.
    * @param s the input complex number as string
    * @return a <code>ComplexNumber</code> which is represented by the string.
    */
    public static ComplexNumber parseComplex(String s)
    {
        s = s.replaceAll(" ","");
        ComplexNumber parsed = null;
        if(s.contains(String.valueOf("+")) || (s.contains(String.valueOf("-")) && s.lastIndexOf('-') > 0))
        {
            String re = "";
            String im = "";
            s = s.replaceAll("i","");
            s = s.replaceAll("I","");
            if(s.indexOf('+') > 0)
            {
                re = s.substring(0,s.indexOf('+'));
                im = s.substring(s.indexOf('+')+1,s.length());
                parsed = new ComplexNumber(Double.parseDouble(re),Double.parseDouble(im));
            }
            else if(s.lastIndexOf('-') > 0)
            {
                re = s.substring(0,s.lastIndexOf('-'));
                im = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf('-')+1,s.length());
                parsed = new ComplexNumber(Double.parseDouble(re),-Double.parseDouble(im));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Pure imaginary number
            if(s.endsWith("i") || s.endsWith("I"))
            {
                s = s.replaceAll("i","");
                s = s.replaceAll("I","");
                parsed = new ComplexNumber(0, Double.parseDouble(s));
            }
            // Pure real number
            else
            {
                parsed = new ComplexNumber(Double.parseDouble(s),0);
            }
        }
        return parsed;
    }
    /**
    * Checks if the passed <code>ComplexNumber</code> is equal to the current.
    * @param z the complex number to be checked
    * @return true if they are equal, false otherwise
    */
    @Override
    public final boolean equals(Object z) 
    {
        if (!(z instanceof ComplexNumber))
            return false;
        ComplexNumber a = (ComplexNumber) z;
        return (real == a.real) && (imaginary == a.imaginary);
    }
    /**
    * The inverse/reciprocal of the complex number.
    * @return the reciprocal of current complex number.
    */
    public ComplexNumber inverse()
    {
        return divide(new ComplexNumber(1,0),this);
    }
    /**
    * Formats the Complex number as x+yi or r.cis(theta)
    * @param format_id the format ID <code>ComplexNumber.XY</code> or <code>ComplexNumber.RCIS</code>.
    * @return a string representation of the complex number
    * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the format_id does not match.
    */
    public String format(int format_id) throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
        String out = "";
        if(format_id == XY)
            out = toString();
        else if(format_id == RCIS)
        {
            out = mod()+" cis("+getArg()+")";
        }
        else
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown Complex Number format.");
        }
        return out;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or....... you could just dispense with all of this nonsense and just use the Apache Commons library, which works better than anything here and includes essential operations like complex exponentiation.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/complex.html

but only if you don't feel like re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score -1):

The *correct* way to convert a `String` in the format `(r,i)` into a `Complex` would be to use a regular expression. However if you're new to programming your instructor might suspect you copied that solution from the Internet :)  Try something like this:

```
public static Complex fromString(String str) {
    str = str.substring(1, str.length() - 1);
    String[] parts = str.split(",");
    double r = Double.valueOf(parts[0]);
    double i = Double.valueOf(parts[1]);
    return new Complex(r, i);
}
```

You can find more info about the Java String class here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: I finished all the code, and I think I came across the issue you mentioned. The complex number is unreadable when outputted. However, what you wrote is just as unreadable to me :D. What exactly is going on and how is this conversion working?

Comment: Line by line: (1) strip out the beginning and end parentheses, (2) split the string on the middle comma to get two parts, the real and imaginary numbers, (3-4) the numbers are still Strings so this step converts them into doubles, (5) make a new Complex.  Also, if you're trying to print a Complex using System.out.println(), you will need to add a method to Complex with this signature: `public String toString()` that creates and returns a string representation of the Complex.

Comment: There is no such thing as 'the *correct* way'. There are ways and ways, and what you use depends on many factors. This is a working solution but it has a significant performance overhead compared to others.

Answer (score -1):

This is not correct!

```
 public static ComplexNumber exp(ComplexNumber z)
{
    double a = z.real;
    double b = z.imaginary;
    double r = Math.exp(a);
    a = r*Math.cos(b);
    b = r*Math.sin(b);
    return new ComplexNumber(a,b);
}
```

should be

```
 public static ComplexNumber exp(ComplexNumber z)
{
    double theta = Math.atan2(r.real/r.imag);
    double r =  mod();
    double a = r*Math.cos(theta );
    double b = r*Math.sin(theta );
    return new ComplexNumber(a,b);
}
```